# Show number in x axis in upsetR package

Tags: r, plot, intersection

It is possible put a value after bar in uspet Graphic?

I want the numbers in the set.size, x - axis

Reproducible example:

```
library(UpSetR)

movies <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "movies.csv", package = "UpSetR"), 
    header = T, sep = ";")
upset(movies, empty.intersections = "on", order.by = "freq")
```

More examples: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/vignettes/basic.usage.html